# Javascript remove special character which not stick with words

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to remove all special character which not stick with words. for example:

**Lorem! ?! ipsum.. do'lor .. sit-sit ( amet, )**

Will become like this :

**Lorem! ipsum.. do'lor sit-sit amet,**

I use this regex `replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')` but it will remove all special character. Please help me.. Thank you ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Javascript RegExp doesn't support lookahead/lookbehind, but you can specify a function as the replacement parameter. The following code snippet doesn't yield the exact results you require and is not very optimized, but maybe it points you in the right direction:

```
var text = 'Lorem! ?! ipsum.. do\'lor .. sit-sit ( amet, )';
text.replace(/(.)([^\w])/g, function($0, $1, $2) {
    if (/\w/.test($1)) {
        return $1 + $2;
    }
    if (/[^\w\s]/.test($1)) {
        return /\s/.test($2) ? ' ' : '';
    }
    return $1;
});
```

The replacement function gets the complete match as first parameter ($0) and also all other matching groups ($1, $2, ...). The return value of the function is then used as the actual replacement.